# How to batch process RAW files for timelapse photography? (preferably with Python)

Tags: timelapse, batch, photoshop-elements

I have a set of 200+ RAW files that need to process for a timelapse. They were taken in a 30s time interval during sunrise. I had to change the shutter time several times to adjust exposure on the images.

My usual process is to load files in Photoshop Elements. Here I have a set of preferences I can adjust:

[image: Photoshop Elements screenshot]

I adjust all of them, and wouldn't want to miss any.

However, the set of RAW files I have now requires me to adjust some of these settings individually. Say: first image +1.0EV, last image -1.0EV, interpolation in between. Similar procedure for the temperature.

This is quite cumbersome with the given software. I have to play around a lot to find good settings, manually doing this is not an option.

I am familiar with Python and was looking into [rawpy](https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/rawpy.RawPy.html) and [rawkit](https://rawkit.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/). As far as I could tell, they obviously don't have the same functionality. At least the "Clarity" function is not available.

I would like to know what (other) options I do have to do this? 
What is your experience?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which software to assemble a time-lapse from images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/which-software-to-assemble-a-time-lapse-from-images)
From that question, I think especially [the answer mentioning LRTimelapse](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/24549/9161) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Darktable is scriptable with Lua: https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/lua_chapter.html. Similarly, Rawtherapee can be called from a CLI so should be scriptable: https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Command-Line_Options

Comment: @saaru-lindestøkke Yes, LRTimelapse is exactly what I was looking for. It is the most convenient.

Comment: @eric-shain I was also looking into Darktable, but Lua seems to be a bit too advanced for me. I might test Rawtherapee.

Comment: Lua is pretty easy to pick up. If you can write Python it should be a snap to learn.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of thing I've been doing with a set of Python components I've developed which I call "Pyctools". It's all a bit experimental and definitely not user friendly - I wrote it for my own purposes so it reflects my mindset.
https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/pyctools-demo/tree/master/src/scripts/photo_processing

If you fancy a challenge, it might be a good starting point for what you want to do.

Comment: This looks like a nice tool. I will definitely try it out at some point.

Comment: Not so much a tool as a set of building blocks, so doing anything useful will involve some work. I'll be interested to hear how you get on if you do have a go.